# Color escape codes in pretty printed columns

Tags: bash, unix, escaping, multiple-columns

I have a tab-delimited text file which I send to `column` to "pretty print" a table.

**Original file:**

```
1<TAB>blablablabla<TAB>aaaa bbb ccc
2<TAB>blabla<TAB>xxxxxx
34<TAB>okokokok<TAB>zzz yyy
```

Using `column -s$'\t' -t <original file>`, I get

```
1  blablablabla aaaa bbb xxx
2  blabla       xxxxxx
34 okokokok     zzz yyy
```

as desired. Now I want to add colors to the columns. I tried to add the escape codes around each tab-delimited field in the original file. `column` successfully prints in color, but the columns are no longer aligned. Instead, it just prints the TAB separators verbatim.

The question is: how can I get the columns aligned, but also with unique colors?

I've thought of two ways to achieve this:

1. Adjust the `column` parameters to make the alignment work with color codes
2. Redirect the output of column to another file, and do a search+replace on the first two whitespace-delimited fields (the first two columns are guaranteed to *not* contain spaces; the third column most likely will contain spaces, but no TAB characters)

Problem is, I'm not sure how to do either of those two...

For reference, here is what I'm passing to `column`:

[image: Original file with color codes]

Note that the fields are indeed separated by TAB characters. I've confirmed this with `od`.

**edit:**

There doesn't seem to be an issue with the colorization. I already have the file shown above with the color codes working. The issue is `column` won't align once I send it input with escape codes. I am thinking of passing the fields *without* color codes to `column`, then copying the exact number of spaces `column` output between each field, and using that in a pretty print scheme.

Comment: I tried this using just "column -t my_file" and don't see any problem with alignment.

Comment: If FIELD3 has spaces in it, it won't work unless you specify a different delimiter. Even so, mine is not aligning the first two columns even though they contain no spaces. Here is the results of `column -t my_file`: http://i.imgur.com/w6i1aGn.png

Comment: Have to leave for today. Will dig more into this tomorrow.. There must a solution. (You could use some more *mighty* language like python or perl of course. But awk + column should work.. don't know why)

Comment: I think it might just be my machine -- it seems to work for other people. I have a fairly old system: `Linux version 2.6.18-238.el5 (mockbuild@x86-012.build.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)) #1 SMP Sun Dec 19 14:22:44 EST 2010`

Answer (score 9):

I would use `awk` for the colorization (`sed` can be used as well):

```
awk '{printf "\033[1;32m%s\t\033[00m\033[1;33m%s\t\033[00m\033[1;34m%s\033[00m\n", $1, $2, $3;}' a.txt
```

and pipe it to `column` for the alignment:

```
... | column -s$'\t' -t
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: How do you preserve the spacing done by `column`? From your `awk` command, it looks like a static number of spaces.

Comment: If I understand, that `awk` command will produce the same output as file I posted above... but I already tried sending that to `column` and it doesn't align right with the escape codes.

Comment: Nope... still prints the TAB instead of aligning. Also, the third field has spaces in it, and this only prints the first word of it.

Comment: How can it be? I've tested with *your* input? Which terminal type are you using?

Comment: Do you have the word `<tab>` as delimiter, not a real tab?

Comment: No, it's a real tab :P I got it to print the whole third field by changing to `awk -F'\t'`, but I can't seem to get around the alignment issue. When I remove the color codes, it works. When I add them, it doesn't.

Comment: My terminal is `xterm-color` and I'm not sure how to check which version of `column` I have...

Comment: Thank you :) I changed the original file above to look more like the real thing. (I had to simplify, it's monstrous)

Comment: You have green ouput only now, but aligment is ok?

Comment: strange `awk` problem!

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a bash version of column (similar to the one from util-linux) which works with color codes:

```
#!/bin/bash
which sed >> /dev/null || exit 1

version=1.0b
editor="Norman Geist"
last="04 Jul 2016"

# NOTE: Brilliant pipeable tool to format input text into a table by 
# NOTE: an configurable seperation string, similar to column
# NOTE: from util-linux, but we are smart enough to ignore 
# NOTE: ANSI escape codes in our column width computation
# NOTE: means we handle colors properly ;-)

# BUG : none

addspace=1
seperator=$(echo -e " ")
columnW=()
columnT=()

while getopts "s:hp:v" opt; do
  case $opt in
s ) seperator=$OPTARG;;
p ) addspace=$OPTARG;;
v ) echo "Version $version last edited by $editor ($last)"; exit 0;;
h ) echo "column2 [-s seperator] [-p padding] [-v]"; exit 0;;
* ) echo "Unknow comandline switch \"$opt\""; exit 1
  esac
done
shift $(($OPTIND-1))

if [ ${#seperator} -lt 1 ]; then
  echo "Error) Please enter valid seperation string!"
  exit 1
fi

if [ ${#addspace} -lt 1 ]; then
  echo "Error) Please enter number of addional padding spaces!"
  exit 1
fi

#args: string
function trimANSI()
{
  TRIM=$1
  TRIM=$(sed 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g' <<< $TRIM); #trim color codes
  TRIM=$(sed 's/\x1b(B//g'         <<< $TRIM); #trim sgr0 directive
  echo $TRIM
}

#args: len
function pad()
{
  for ((i=0; i<$1; i++))
  do 
echo -n " "
  done
}

#read and measure cols
while read ROW
do
  while IFS=$seperator read -ra COLS; do
ITEMC=0
for ITEM in "${COLS[@]}"; do
  SITEM=$(trimANSI "$ITEM"); #quotes matter O_o
  [ ${#columnW[$ITEMC]} -gt 0 ] || columnW[$ITEMC]=0
  [ ${columnW[$ITEMC]} -lt ${#SITEM} ] && columnW[$ITEMC]=${#SITEM}
  ((ITEMC++))
done
columnT[${#columnT[@]}]="$ROW"
  done <<< "$ROW"
done

#print formatted output
for ROW in "${columnT[@]}"
do
  while IFS=$seperator read -ra COLS; do
ITEMC=0
for ITEM in "${COLS[@]}"; do
  WIDTH=$(( ${columnW[$ITEMC]} + $addspace ))
  SITEM=$(trimANSI "$ITEM"); #quotes matter O_o
  PAD=$(($WIDTH-${#SITEM}))

  if [ $ITEMC -ne 0 ]; then
    pad $PAD
  fi

  echo -n "$ITEM"

  if [ $ITEMC -eq 0 ]; then
    pad $PAD
  fi

  ((ITEMC++))
done
  done <<< "$ROW"
  echo ""
done
```

Example usage:

```
bold=$(tput bold)
normal=$(tput sgr0)
green=$(tput setaf 2)

column2 -s § << END
${bold}First Name§Last Name§City${normal}
${green}John§Wick${normal}§New York
${green}Max§Pattern${normal}§Denver
END
```

Output example:

[image]

Comment: I've tried column2 and it works!! Unfortunately not so fast as column. Here goes the times: column2 did 0.706s/0.599s/0.612s/0.622s while original column did 0.012s/0.009s/0.009s/0.010s.
It makes difference when the user is waiting for the information to be shown. But.... as column won't work with color escape codes, I'll continue using color2 and +1 to the author.

Comment: Brilliant! Can I use this in an open source project I am working on? I just sent you a mail with more information :)

Comment: is this available on GitHub? if so you should provide a link, I'd love to give it a star :)

Comment: @HudsonSantos I made a Perl-based version of `column2` that is way faster (column: `0m0,059s/0m0,015s/0m0,015s`, while mine `0m0,092s/0m0,000s/0m0,000s`). I'll post it on Github (making credit to this answer obviously) and share it with you guys

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70513399/8965861

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `printf` to format the ouput as well :

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r c1 c2 c3; do
    tput setaf 1; printf '%-10s' "$c1"
    tput setaf 2; printf '%-30s' "$c2"
    tput setaf 3; printf '%-30s' "$c3"
    tput sgr0; echo
done < file
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the `tput` command usage :) .. But the aligment isn't ok yet. You should pipe to `column`

Comment: Still doesn't work piping to `column`... I think the issue here is with `column` tripping up on color codes, not the colorization itself.

Answer (score 2):

## 2021 Updated BASH Answer

### TL;DR

I really liked [@NORMAN GEIST's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38762316/8965861) but was way too slow for what i needed... So i coded my own version of his script, this time written in **Perl** (stdin looping and formatting) + **Bash** (only for presentation/help).

You can find the **[full code here](https://github.com/LukeSavefrogs/column_ansi)** with an explanation on how to use it.

It is comprehensive of:

- A Bash `column`-like command interface (*same parameters* like `-t`, `-s`, `-o`)
- Exaustive *help* with `column_ansi --help` or `column_ansi -h`
- Option to *horizontally center*.

The actual "core" code can broken down to [only the Perl part](https://github.com/LukeSavefrogs/column_ansi/blob/main/column_ansi.sh#L58-L167).

### Background and differences

I needed to format a **very long** `awk`-generated colored output (more than **300 lines**) into a nice table.
I first thought of using `column`, but as i discovered it didn't take into consideration ANSI characters, since the output would come out **not aligned**.

After searching a bit on Google i found [@NORMAN GEIST's interesting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38762316/8965861) on SO which dynamically calculated the width of every single column in the output after removing the ANSI characters and THEN it built the table.

It was all good, but it was taking **way too long to load** (as someone pointed in the comments)...

So i tried to *convert* @NORMAN GEIST's `column2` from `bash` to `perl` and my god if there was a change!

After trying out this version in my production script the time used to display data **dropped from 30s to <1s**!!

Enjoy!

Comment: Brillant, thanks for this solution!

Comment: Thanks @carlfriedrich :). I'm happy you liked it. Hope it will help you as much as it was useful to me

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the next version v2.40 of [util-linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux) / [column](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html) will handle text containing [Fe Escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Fe_Escape_sequences) from [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) properly.

With [this change](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/pull/2767), programs that output text with ANSI sequences will be handled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanted to selectively colorise values in a column depending on its value. Let's say I want `okokokok` to be green and `blabla` to be red.

I can do it such way (the idea is to colorise values of columns *after* columnisation):

```
GREEN_SED='\\033[0;32m'
RED_SED='\\033[0;31m'
NC_SED='\\033[0m' # No Color

column -s$'\t' -t <original file> | echo -e "$(sed -e "s/okokokok/${GREEN_SED}okokokok${NC_SED}/g" -e "s/blabla/${RED_SED}blabla${NC_SED}/g")"
```

Alternatively, with a variable:

```
DATA=$(column -s$'\t' -t <original file>)

GREEN_SED='\\033[0;32m'
RED_SED='\\033[0;31m'
NC_SED='\\033[0m' # No Color
echo -e "$(sed -e "s/okokokok/${GREEN_SED}okokokok${NC_SED}/g" -e "s/blabla/${RED_SED}blabla${NC_SED}/g" <<< "$DATA")"
```

Take a note of that additional backslash in values of color definitions. It is made for sed to not interpret an origingal backsash.

This is a result:

[image]