# How to format columns with printf in bash when tput is used

Tags: bash, formatting, printf, tput

Using tput changes the length of the string and so columns are not aligned. How to fix this?

Tried following code in bash script.

```
B="$(tput bold)" # Bold text
N="$(tput sgr0)" # Normal text

function testing(){

IN="KEYS | VALUES | DESCRIPTION
id | ${B}10${N} or ${B}20${N} | Enter ID. Default is ${B}10${N}.
status | ${B}true${N} or ${B}false${N} | Enter status of something. Default is ${B}true${N}.
style | Example: Standard | Give suitable standard."

    IFS= 
    while read -r lines; do
        IFS='|' read -r -a array <<< "$lines"
        printf "%-35s %-35s %-s\n" "${array[0]}" "${array[1]}" "${array[2]}"
    done <<< "$IN"

    read -p "$*"
    exit 0
}
```

Output is something like:

```
    KEYS          VALUES                              DESCRIPTION
    id            **10** or **20**           Enter ID. Default is **10**.
    status        **true** or **false**      Enter status of something. Default is **true**.
    style         Example: Standard                   Give suitable standard.
```

Expected to be:

```
    KEYS          VALUES                              DESCRIPTION
    id            **10** or **20**                    Enter ID. Default is **10**.
    status        **true** or **false**               Enter status of something. Default is **true**.
    style         Example: Standard                   Give suitable standard.
```

Comment: when I run the code in my bash env I find that the 2 problematic `DESCRIPTION` strings lose 20 spaces of indent; lengths of the vars (`${#B}` & `${#N}`) are 4 and 6 chars, respectively; these vars show up twice in the `VALUES` field for a total of 20 (non-printable) chars; `printf/%s` counts the 20 non-printable chars as part of the output hence the appearance that 20 spaces are 'lost' (ie, `printf` **is** printing 35 chars ... it's just that 20 of those chars are non-printing); "Duh, Mark!" ?  what I don't know is: does `printf` have a flag to ignore non-printable chars for format purposes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Color escape codes in pretty printed columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151601/color-escape-codes-in-pretty-printed-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment:

- when I run the code in my bash env I find that the 2 problematic `DESCRIPTION` strings lose 20 spaces of indent
- lengths of the vars (`${#B}` & `${#N}`) are 4 and 6 chars, respectively
- these vars show up twice in the `VALUES` field for a total of 20 (non-printable) chars
- `printf/%s` counts the 20 non-printable chars as part of the output hence the appearance that 20 spaces are 'lost' (ie, `printf` **is** printing 35 chars ... it's just that 20 of those chars are non-printing)

What if we measure the length of the second field - with and without the special chars 
- and then use the difference (ie, the number of non-printable characters) to increase the format width of the second field of the `printf` command?

We'll store the length of the second field (which includes our special characters) in a new variable `len2`:

```
len2="${#array[1]}"
```

Next we want to strip out the special characters and measure the length of the resulting string and place in variable `lenx`:

```
x="${array[1]//${B}/}"    # strip out all occurrences of variable 'B'
x="${x//${N}/}"           # strip out all occurrences of variable 'N'
lenx=${#x}
```

NOTE: I had some problems getting `tr` and `sed` to properly strip out the special characters; I'm open to suggestions. On the plus side ... I'm not spawning any sub processes.

We'll store the new format width in variable `w2` ('w'idth for field '2') like such:

```
w2=$(( 35 + len2 - lenx ))
```

And the new `printf` format string becomes:

```
printf "%-35s %-${w2}s %-s\n" ...
```

Pulling it all together we get:

```
B="$(tput bold)" # Bold text
N="$(tput sgr0)" # Normal text

function testing(){

IN="KEYS | VALUES | DESCRIPTION
id | ${B}10${N} or ${B}20${N} | Enter ID. Default is ${B}10${N}.
status | ${B}true${N} or ${B}false${N} | Enter status of something. Default is ${B}true${N}.
style | Example: Standard | Give suitable standard."

    IFS= 
    while read -r lines; do
        IFS='|' read -r -a array <<< "$lines"

        len2="${#array[1]}"

        x="${array[1]//${B}/}"
        x="${x//${N}/}"
        lenx=${#x}

        w2=$(( 35 + len2 - lenx ))
   #    echo "w2 = ${w2}"

        printf "%-35s %-${w2}s %-s\n" "${array[0]}" "${array[1]}" "${array[2]}"
    done <<< "$IN"

    read -p "$*"
    exit 0
}
```

Running the script in my bash env generates:

```
$ testing
KEYS                                 VALUES                              DESCRIPTION
id                                   10 or 20                            Enter ID. Default is 10.
status                               true or false                       Enter status of something. Default is true.
style                                Example: Standard                   Give suitable standard.
```

NOTE: The bold fields do print as **bold** on my terminal ... they just don't copy/display as **bold** in the above answer.

If you uncomment the line - `echo "w2 = ${w2}"` - you should find (for the 2 lines of interest) that we're going to use a format width of `55` for the second field (ie, the desired `35` plus an extra `20` to compensate for the 20 characters worth of non-printable characters).

Comment: Your solution works exactly as needed. Thanks for the help! Hopefully in future there will be a flag for printf for such cases.

Comment: Good to hear, though doubtful we'll see such a flag anytime (soon)